# How to save my entry through a UserChangeForm?

Tags: django

I created a UserChangeForm to edit the teacher information. When I submit the form, it didn't save the entry to the database.

I need two users for two custom views, but the userchangeform is not saving subject to the teacher's table. Meanwhile, the usercreationform had no issue at all.
models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    users = (
        ('student', 'Student'),
        ('teacher', 'Teacher'),
)
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user.user_type = "teacher"
    id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    #return the doctors' name
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.user_type == "student":
            Student.objects.create(user=instance)
        elif instance.user_type == "teacher":
            Teacher.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

forms.py

```
class TeacherForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ('subject',)
```

views.py

```
def Edit_Teacher(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TeacherForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:   
        form = TeacherForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        args = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'registration/edit_teacher.html', args)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a `ModelForm` then you need to pass an instance of that model to update the object. So you'd need to pass the `Teacher` instance which relates to the logged in user, based on the code you've supplied.

views.py

```
def edit_teacher(request):
    try:
        teacher = request.user.teacher
    except AttributeError:
        raise  # Deal with error here

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TeacherForm(request.POST, instance=teacher)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')

    form = TeacherForm(instance=teacher)
    cxt = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'registration/edit_teacher.html', cxt)
```

Comment: @JoseLopez Great news!